# How to copy numbers from an array into a binary file one-at-a-time?

Tags: c, arrays, file, printf, fwrite

I am trying to figure out a way to copy numbers from an array into a binary file **one-number-at-a-time**. I am able to copy an entire array into a binary file using **fwrite** but I would like to know if there is a method of being able to do so **one-number-at-a-time**.

In the function **CopyArrayToBinary**, how can I modify **fwrite** to be able to print one number at a time to the binary file.

My program is able to compile with no issues, Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void CopyArrayToBinary(int a[]);
void AppendNumbers(int a[]);
void DisplayBinFile(char fname[]);

int main()
{
     int a[6]={30,60,10,90,40,70};

     CopyArrayToBinary(a);
     AppendNumbers(a);
     DisplayBinFile("binary.txt");

     printf("\n\n");
     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}

 void CopyArrayToBinary(int a[])
 {
     FILE * fbin;
     fbin = fopen("binary.txt","w");
     int i;

     fwrite((char *)a, sizeof(int), 6 , fbin);

     free(a);
     fclose(fbin);

     return 0;
 }

  void AppendNumbers(int a[])
 {
  int c[4]={15,45,35,74};
  FILE * fpointer;
  fpointer = fopen("binary.txt", "a");

  fwrite((char *)c,sizeof(int),4,fpointer);

  free(a);
  fclose(fpointer);

 return 0;
}

void DisplayBinFile(char fname[])
{
  FILE * fpointer;
  int i ;
  int b[10];

    fpointer = fopen(fname, "r");
    fread((char *)b, sizeof(int),10,fpointer);

  //DISPLAY ARRAY B
  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
 {
     printf("%d ",b[i]);
 }

  fclose(fpointer);

 return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: `fread((char *)b, sizeof(int),10,fpointer);`is wrong. You try to read 10 integers (that is usually 40 bytes) into a 10 byte buffer.

Comment: What's wrong with the `CopyArrayToBinary` function ? Apart from hardoding the length to write and no error checking done, the function should work as expected. You write 6 ints to the file. If you want to write one int instead of 6 ints write `fwrite((char *)a, sizeof(int), 1 , fbin);`.

Comment: `free(a);` You are freeing an object that was **not** obtained by malloc().

Comment: The free(a) is trying to free a stack variable [defined in main]--not a good thing, so remove it.  Even if it were malloc'ed, you wouldn't want to free it in the copy func, because it would be junk when you call append. Also, fwrite takes a const void *, so no need for the cast to char *.  As to the one-at-a-time, do:  for (i = 0;  i < 6;  ++i) fwrite(&a[i],sizeof(int),1,fbin);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fwrite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm) prototype is:

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

Where `nmemb` is the number of elements you want to write.

Take notes that if you want to add a single char per time you must to open file with `"w+"` (or better `"wb+"`) option to append chars at the end of file.

---

**Your code could not work properly** due to the free(a) instruction in `CopyArrayToBinary` function. You cannot free a  pointer to a stack allocated array. Use `free` to free heap `malloc`ated variables.